# Is there a way I can use Apache Syncope only for authorization?

Tags: java, authentication, authorization, apache-syncope

I would like to use UI authorization feature to manage roles and permissions, 
but I have very tricky logic for authentication and I want to keep it outside of syncope,

Is the a way I can use it only for authorization purposes?

For example can I call endpoint /{user}/{permission} and get back status on this permission for this user?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes, you can store authorizations on Syncope and later retrieve them via REST.

For further discussion, please join Syncope user mailing list and let's continue there:

http://syncope.apache.org/mailing-lists.html